# ImageMagick center image group on canvas

Tags: php, shell, command-line, imagemagick, imagick

I am outputting a banner with an image to the left and some text to the right. This is working well, however the positioning is very manual. I'd like to be able to group the $robot_image and the $robot_name text into one image, and then center that image group on the background 1400x500 canvas. Any ideas how I'd achieve this? The attached image is what I'd like to achieve: The robot + text centered as a group on the canvas

```
$banner = exec("convert {$robot_image} -resize 500x500 -gravity west -geometry +100+100 -background '#{$hex}' -extent 1400x500 -font 'SignPainter.ttc' -pointsize 300 -fill 'white' -strokewidth 20 -fill white \
-stroke 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)' -annotate +550+40 '{$robot_name}' \
-stroke none -annotate +550+40 '{$robot_name}' output.jpg");
```

[image]

Comment: Create a text image using label: on your background color. Then +append it to the right of your robot. Then either -gravity center -extent it with the same background color or just convert ... -gravity center -composite it onto a background image of the size you want. See -extent and convert -composite and label: docs.  E.G. https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent, https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose.  There are many ways to do this.

Comment: You can also create a transparent background image, convert ... -composite the robot and then add the text with -annotate. Then flatten the result onto your background color

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to show me a commend line example for this. Would really appreciate it

Comment: Examples at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/5603#discussioncomment-3766071

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how I achieved it:

```
convert robot.png -resize 500x500 -background "#31BEFF" -size 600x -font 'SignPainter.ttf' -gravity center label:"RobotName" -alpha off +smush -50 -gravity center -background "#31BEFF" -extent 1400x500 result.jpg
```